# HttpClient 3.1 hangs without throwing an exception even though timeout is set

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm writing an application for a Windows Mobile device that only supports Java 1.4. so I'm using the old HttpClient 3.1. The timeout works fine most of the time, but randomly it hangs the entire app for a minute trying to send a request. I've tried to set the timeout as the following:

```css
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(myJSONString,"application/json","UTF-8");
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/rest/");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
postMethod.setRequestHeader(new Header("Accept","application/json"));
postMethod.setRequestHeader(new Header("Content-Type","application/json"));
try
{
  client.setTimeout(2000);
  client.setConnectionTimeout(2000);
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(postMethod);  
  if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    System.out.println("Success!");
  }
  else
    System.out.println("Error");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Does your server ever receive the request that eventually hangs your client app?

Comment: Yes, this works most of the time, I mean the server receive the request but eventually it just hangs.